# How to get commit message in gitlab server side pre-receive hooks

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

I am trying to develop a server side pre-receive hook on gitlab. where I should get the commit message from the new commits which are getting added.

I tried using the `git log --pretty=%B -n 1`. This is returning the old committed message. How can I get the commit message form the new unaccepted changes ?

When I tried to get the refname or argument in to the script it did not hold any values. (thinking that might be of help)

```
#!/bin/bash
ref_name=$refname
echo $ref_name
ref_name=$1
echo $ref_name
echo "refname"
issue=`git log --pretty=%B -n 1`
echo $issue #this is printing old commit message
```

Result:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 306 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote: refname
```

Comment: @phd can you help me on how to resolve that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The pre-receive hook gets a list of references and their old and new versions on standard input. So you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read old new ref
do
    # ref deleted; skip
    echo "$new" | grep -qsE '^0+$' && continue

    issue=$(git log --pretty=%B -n 1 "$new")
    echo "issue is $issue"
done
```

Note that this assumes that you only care about the head commit at the latest ref and that you're okay with doing this for tags as well. If you only want branches, and you want to traverse all the commits, then you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read old new ref
do
    case $ref in
        refs/heads/*)
            if echo "$new" | grep -qsE '^0+$'
            then
                # ref deleted; skip
                :
            elif echo "$old" | grep -qsE '^0+$'
            then
                # new branch
                # do something with this output
                git log --pretty=%B "$new"
            else
                # update
                # do something with this output
                git log --pretty=%B "$old".."$new"
            fi;;
        *)
            continue;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: One quick question  when i try to echo the old, new and ref. it prints nothing, why is it not getting printed and when i try to get all the commits between old and new using the command `git log --pretty=%B "$old".."$new"` it gives a error like "fatal: ..: '..' is outside repository". How can i loop through all the commit messages.

Comment: That error message means that `$old` and `$new` aren't being filled in. Please post the code you're using so we can see what might be wrong.

Comment: Never mind of my error. I was trying to use variables out side the while loop that's why i got the error. got it fixed. Thank you very much,  your solution helped.